# how to download xml files from FTPserver using FTPclient in java

Tags: java

problem when i was downloading file from ftp server to local machine the files are copying but the file content is not copying it shows as zero bytes file it does no contain anthing in it.

Please some one can help me..

Thanks 
Nagaraju

Comment: can you paste the code to download and write the file to the local file system?

Comment: There's probably something wrong in your code.

Comment: @Nagaraju : I'm facing the same problem. How did you solve this issue?